# How to toggle visibility of divs based on keyword filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I have this HTML of some cards that contain different keywords:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags">
        <span><a href="#">Healthcare</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags">
        <span><a href="#">Finance</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this HTML of some pills that can be toggled on/off:

```
<div class="hashtags">
    <span class="active"><a href="#">Finance</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"><a href="#">Healthcare</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"><a href="#">Managed Services</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
</div>
```

The idea is to be able to click on a pill for "Finance", and only those items that contain "Finance" in their hashtag class will be displayed, and all other items are hidden. I've tried searching for how to filter/toggle based on content, but can't seem to find anything yet. Here's my JS so far, which only toggles the active/inactive classes of the pill styling:

```
    $('.hashtags>span').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

I know there's a way to lookup HTML and compare strings in JS or jQuery...but not sure that's the best approach. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: when you say > only those items that contain "Finance" in their hashtag class < you mean if the value of the `href` contains the word Finance, or if the `value` of the anchor tag is Finance?

Comment: Are you searching to do that "filtering" directly inside the the selector someghing like (not existence) $( ".item .hashtags a[content=blabla]" ) or the like? Doubt it, but I'll give a search

Comment: If the visible text value of the <a> tag contains Finance, it should be displayed and all other divs hidden.

Comment: CSS selectors based on content do not exist. At one point a pseudo for :contains was proposed but never made it in. To do anything based on content you need to use javascript. Is it possible to add classes to the elements you want to filter. Add a finance class and so on...

Comment: @RiccardoC not sure...that's what I'm trying to figure out. I wonder if Arrays might help? Like maybe I need to store all the a tag values from the hashtag class into an array, and then when one of those is clicked, it somehow compares it to the a tags within all the item divs?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I think the hashtags may change often though, so I'm thinking JS may be the way to go. Good to know about :contains...hopefully it'll make the cut one day. :)

Comment: Give a look at :contains ( https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ )

Comment: To be clear the contains jquery provides is a code based solution they include in their library though @GabeMedina

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a complete example. I add comments to code

```js
$('.hashtags > span').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // first we store value
  var storedValue = $(this).text();
  // send it to a function
  highlightHashtag(storedValue);
});


var highlightHashtag = function(value) {
  // iterate through all
  $('.hashtags > span').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== value) {
      //  if doesnt match, inactive
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('inactive');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  
};
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:green;
}

.inactive {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags">
        <span><a href="#">Healthcare</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags">
        <span><a href="#">Finance</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i understand you question, first of all, hide all .items, then show all .items with a hashtag containing the text you are selected.
like this (untested)

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
$('.hashtags>span').unbind('click').click(function() {
    var text = $(this)
            .toggleClass('inactive')
            .toggleClass('active');
    var items = $('.item').hide();
    $('.hashtags>span.active').each(function(){
        var t = $(this).find('a:first').text() ;
        items.each(function(){
            var i = $(this);
            //find all items containing a a with the activated hashtag text
            if(i.find('.hashtags>span>a:contains(\'' + t + '\')').length > 0) {
                i.show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great! It's very close to what I was looking for. The only issue now is that when you click a second time to toggle it back to inactive class, it doesn't hide like it was originally. Should the i.show somehow be a toggle? Thanks again...this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is better if you add some custom tag into you html. Look at my quick example:

In the html you can add some custom attributes like data-something that can be really usefull.

CSS only highlight which class is on which object

You can try my code down here or look at it on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w19ytk8p/

```js
$('.hashtags>span').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var tag = $(this).attr("data-tag");
    var related = [];
    $('.hashtags').each(function(index){
        $(this).children( "span" ).removeClass("active");
        $(this).children( "span" ).addClass("inactive");
     if($(this).attr("data-tag") !== undefined && $(this).attr("data-tag").indexOf(tag)>-1) {related.push(this);}
    });
    $(related).each(function(){
     $(this).children( "span" ).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).children( "span" ).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.inactive > a{
    color: red;
}
.active > a{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags" data-tag="healthcare finance">
        <span><a href="#">Healthcare</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="hashtags"  data-tag="finance mobility">
        <span><a href="#">Finance</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hashtags">
    <span class="active"  data-tag="finance"><a href="#">Finance</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"  data-tag="healthcare"><a href="#">Healthcare</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"  data-tag="managedServices"><a href="#">Managed Services</a></span>
    <span class="inactive"  data-tag="mobility"><a href="#">Mobility</a></span>
</div>
```